# what annotation to add for the rule to pass the "larastan" test?

Tags: laravel

I am using larastan with laravel 10.

I work with the maximum level: 9

And I can't fix errors returned by larastan in form request. Example for this rule :

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'name' => [
            'required',
            Rule::unique('domains', 'name')->where(function ($query) {
                return $query->where('organization_id', $this->route('organization')->id);
            }),
        ],
    ];
}
```

The error is :

```
Method App\Http\Requests\StoreDomainRequest::rules() return type has no value type specified in iterable type
```

I have tried to add some annotations, like this one :

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule|array|string>
 */
```

without success.

One workaround could be to modify the *phpstan.neon* file , adding this line :
**checkMissingIterableValueType: false**

In this case I have no more errors. But I would prefer not to use this workaround.

So how to do ?

Comment: it should be `array<string, string|array<\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule|array|string>>` though I think because you can have either `'key' => 'rule1|rule2'` or `'key' => [ 'rule1', 'rule2' ]` per array entry

Comment: Thanks apokryfos for the answer. I tried your solution, without success.

Comment: When I add this annotation it works : **@return array<string, mixed>**. But isn't that too easy a solution?

Comment: @Dom I think the error is that, when you define `array` without specifying index type and value type(s), it errors out. So, any form of `array<string, xxxx|yyyy|array>` will fail, it should be `array<string, xxx|yyyy|array<string, whatever>>`, and maybe then it will work. To try it out, use `array<string, string|array<\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule|array<mixed, mixed>|string>>` or just remove that array because your example has no array inside (just for testing purposes), let me now if that worked or not

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Matias' explanations, I think I finally understood how return code declarations work. Thanks Matias.

I made a drawing to clear my mind and help other people.

Now I have reached larastan level 9 without ignoring some things in the **phpstan.neon**

[image]

Comment: More than glad to be of help. I never used Larastan at maximum level, but I used it bedore and is pretty neat. I did end up having issues like yours, so sometimes it is a pain until you truly learn and understand how it works and what it is trying to tell you. You will eventually flow with it!